# CHAR in PostgreSQL having 2 possible lengths

Tags: database, postgresql

Let's assume I have an attribute that is going to contain some text and can either be of a fixed size of 10 characters or of a fixed size of 20 characters but cannot contain text with any other length.

I could use `VARCHAR(20)` in order to save text for both cases but this would allow strings of different lengths to be saved in my relation, e.g. strings with 15 characters.

Is there any type in PostgreSQL that would be similar to something like `CHAR(10) OR CHAR(20)` or do I have to implement my own constraint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a check constraint:

```
create table foo
(
  some_code varchar not null,  
  constraint check_length check (length(some_code) in (10,20))
);
```

**Edit**

If you want to have that as a reusable data type you can create a domain:

```
create domain fixed_size_text 
  as text not null 
  constraint check_length check (length(value) in (10,20);

create table foo
(
   some_code fixed_size_text
);
```

---

Btw: you almost never want a column defined as `char(n)` as that is padded to the defined maximum length. So if you store `'x'` in a `char(50)` column you will effectively store `x` and 49 spaces.

Comment: so I guess there is no type for this?

Comment: @foobar: you can create a domain if you want.